# Python Asyncio blocking when using queues

Tags: python, queue, python-asyncio

I'm trying to use asyncio with both a sync (would be the rest of the python program) and an async bloc and have the sync bloc send data through asyncio.queues.

Without the queueing everythig works fine.
but when I'm sending data in the queue it seems to block.
I'm trying different ways with get_nowait, etc... but with no success so far.

```py
import asyncio
import time

queue = asyncio.Queue()

async def processor() -> None:
    print("Started proc")
    while True:
        print("waiting for quee")
        msg = await queue.get()
        print(f"Got command from queue: {msg}")
        # do something
        await asyncio.sleep(5)


def run_sync(url: str) -> int:
    while 1:
        print("Sending HTTP request")
        input("enter to send message to queue\n")
        queue.put_nowait(url)
        
        #do other work
        time.sleep(10)
        


async def run_sync_threaded( url: str) -> int:
    return await asyncio.to_thread(run_sync, url)

async def main() -> None:


    await asyncio.gather(
        processor(),
        run_sync_threaded("https://www.example.com"), 
    )


asyncio.run(main())
```

EDIT:
Got this working, but looks like a work around instead of a proper solution. I don't know feels not very stable

```py
import asyncio
import time

queue = asyncio.Queue()
async def processor() -> None:
    print("Started proc")
    while True:
        print("waiting for quee")
        msg = await queue.get()
        print(f"Got command from queue: {msg}")
        # do something
        await asyncio.sleep(5)


async def async_send(url):
    print(f'Adding {url} to queue')
    queue.put_nowait(url)

def send(url, loop):
    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(async_send(url), loop)


def run_sync(url: str, loop) -> int:
    while 1:
        input("enter to send message to queue\n")
        send(url, loop)
        #do other work
        time.sleep(3)
        


async def run_sync_threaded( url: str, loop) -> int:
    return await asyncio.to_thread(run_sync, url, loop)

async def main() -> None:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    t = asyncio.create_task( processor())
    t2 = asyncio.create_task(run_sync_threaded("https://www.example.com", loop))

    asyncio.gather(
    await t,  
    await t2
    )


    # This does not work
    # asyncio.gather(
    # await processor(),  
    # await run_sync_threaded("https://www.example.com", loop)
    # )


asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: What is the purpose?

Comment: The idea is to have a more complex with two async pipelines that loop. They read the queues to execute actions. However, I need a synchronous main function that would add data to the queue so the async function can run them in the background without blocking the main function. And the main function (sync) must not block the async function from reading the queue